# Is there any difference between GR's weak-field limit and linearized gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity

I have been studying General Relativity, its weak-field limit and linearized gravity or linearized general relativity.  It is not perfectly clear to me if the terms 'weak-field limit' and 'linearized gravity' are somewhat equivalent to one another.  They seem to be, but can someone enlighten me on this?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think they are the same. If you have some specific references where these terms are used, that could help.